# Is there a function to check the existence of a translation in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have developed a plugin that has over 400 words and phrases. There are a few phrases that are very important to the plugin's functionality, but it is difficult to get 90% of all translations completed [at wordpress.org] just to ensure the essential 20 are set.

I need to check if a translation for the plugin currently exists, otherwise present a fall-back for a limited number of languages.

Example:

```
<?php

if (wp_current_translation_exists())
{
    $local_phrase = __('Some word', 'text-domain');
}
else
{
    $language_code = substr(WP_LANG, 0, 2);
    
    switch ($language_code)
    {
    case 'fr':
        $local_phrase = 'Un mot';
        break;
    case 'de':
        $local_phrase = 'Ein Wort';
        break;
    default:
        $local_phrase = __('Some word', 'text-domain');
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

The missing function is shown as: `wp_current_translation_exists()`.

Comment: Not sure if it exists but you can use the following: `if (__('Some word', 'text-domain') === 'Some word') { //... translation does not exist }`

Comment: I did consider this, but I thought there may be a more elegant way... It is difficult to search for something that offers an answer - so I posted here.

Comment: Also - there are already two translations... so I don't want to check against an increasing number of "positive" strings.

Comment: "Also - there are already two translations... so I don't want to check against an increasing number of "positive" strings" I'm not sure what you mean by this. Would such a function not just do that even if it's WordPress native?

Comment: In this example "Some word" === "Some word" for EN (does exist), but "Some word" !== "Un mot" for (FR does exist) and "Some word" === "Some word" (FR, does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'll be answering my own question... As WordPress defaults to English, I can presume this translation exists and look to others with a word that will vary across languages.

```
<?php

$language_code = strtolower(substr(WP_LANG, 0, 2));

function wp_current_translation_exists($test_word = NULL, $text_domain = NULL)
{
    global $language_code;
    
    if ($test_word == NULL)
    {
        $test_word = 'Welcome';
    }
    
    return ($language_code == 'en' || __($test_word, $text_domain) != $test_word);
}

if (wp_current_translation_exists('Welcome', 'text-domain'))
{
    $local_phrase = __('Some word', 'text-domain');
}
else
{
    switch ($language_code)
    {
    case 'fr':
        $local_phrase = 'Un mot';
        break;
    case 'de':
        $local_phrase = 'Ein Wort';
        break;
    default:
        $local_phrase = __('Some word', 'text-domain');
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

This isn't a great answer, but it is the best one available at the moment.